# How much research is expected before posting for story-identification?

Tags: discussion

[This Hot Question, "Movie about a boy who was born old and grew young"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/213709/movie-about-a-boy-who-was-born-old-and-grew-young) is easily answered by a [quick search of the exact question](https://www.google.com/search?q=Movie+about+a+boy+who+was+born+old+and+grew+young)...I would think at *least* a cursory Google/internet search would be almost required, no?

Or, if they did try, to show their attempts e.g. "I tried finding a movie where a boy is born old, but dies young, but couldn't using these search terms" or something similar?

I found [this 2012](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1872/what-can-we-do-to-encourage-more-questions-with-research-effort) post on how to encourage more research effort, but what would I flag to close as? It's not a duplicate, and it's not too broad, nor any other category really.  That post also suggests adding a comment - which I did, but was deleted by a moderator.

Is it considered somewhat "subjective", in what makes a question easily searchable or not?  Or perhaps I'm overlooking part of what `story-identification` does, or why such an easily answerable question would remain open.

Comment: FWIW google results are tailored to the user and have you ever tried searching for a story id answer before? It is surprisingly difficult, even with "unique" story elements.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - Yeah I know they're pretty tailored for the user.  I guess this specific example would likely show up in the top results for most, but yeah good point!

Comment: If you "bing" the phrase, Benjamin Button is on the first page, but it's not the top (or even top 5) answer

Comment: [Relevant and coincidentally timely main meta post.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/329094/278659)

Comment: Excuse me..."I was the one who wrote that question".. I searched in google and other sites to find the name of the movie and couldn't get it
(and i checked other search engines like duckduckgo,ask,bing) ..unfortunately internet doesn't help much if ur in different countries(i think so)
couldn't get any relevant answers...that's why i asked it in stack exchange I did do some research OKAY! here's the proof just in case: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGmNr.png

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Being "easily searchable" (which is subjective, as you mention - in the linked example, a comment discussion revealed that the OP got a very different set of results from the search as you and other commenters) is **a reason to downvote, not to close-vote**.

The tooltip on the downvote button says "*This question does not show any research effort*". If you feel that a question is so trivially searchable and answerable that the OP must have done no research effort whatsoever, that could be a good reason to downvote. But it doesn't make the question *off-topic* (nor unclear, too broad, or primarily opinion-based). A common Stack Exchange mantra is that [a close vote is not a super downvote](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5498). A question might be *bad*, by way of being poorly researched or some other reason, but that doesn't mean it needs to be *closed* according to the community's defined criteria for closures.

Some Stack Exchange sites do adopt a policy that being "poorly researched" is enough reason to close a question, and they have a custom close reason specifically for such questions. Sci-Fi & Fantasy isn't one of them though.

Comment: I suppose you or another mod deleted the discussion where the OP says they got a very different set of results? Is it possible to undelete some of those comments, at least whilst it is on the HNQ? It's just attracted [another comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/213709/movie-about-a-boy-who-was-born-old-and-grew-young#comment583780_213709) saying "Google the title and it comes up!".

Comment: Thanks for this, that answers it for me.  I'm used to StackOverflow where some research is usually required, or at least expected.  Also, that comment discussion was removed, so I can't see that the OP did indeed try to search.  And I know all of the sites on SE aren't the same, and have different criteria, "rules", etc. so thanks for clarifying... (...and I'm sure a day will come when I ask an "obvious" question too! :P )

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Some of the comments were flagged as unfriendly, following the CoC stuff about not saying "you could Google this in five minutes". Most of the comments there were actually fine, but I thought it'd be better to get rid of them all.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - Yeah, I commented on that too - I'd think that at least one or two of those comments are relevant, and *does* show some effort on OP's part.  That alone would have been enough for me to see they tried, but couldn't find the answer before posting.

Comment: Would it be appropriate for me to ask OP what he searched for? I'm now really curious what his terms were and what the results were on their end. Or is that off-topic?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Ah makes sense, it could be worth editing the question with the OP's comment saying they did search X but it didn't come up if the comment was along those lines just to minimise those comments, especially whilst it's still on the HNQ.

Comment: @BruceWayne The OP shared a [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f_tjtW9c-xLvuO8FAXuY42enkSFXNuoa/view?usp=sharing) to show the result of their search, after another user shared [this](https://i.imgur.com/5gi2Wns.png). But the OP's link doesn't work for me, so I can't actually see their search results ... not sure if that's a problem on my end or if they removed the page.